# how can I pause the executing of a script for a number of seconds

Tags: javascript

there is a built-in function (`sleep()`) in php that delays execution of the current script for a specified number of seconds. it can be put anywhere and it will do the job.
here are its explanation:
http://www.w3schools.com/php/func_misc_sleep.asp
http://php.net/manual/en/function.sleep.php

---

**my question:** does a such function exist in javascript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript generally tries to be **non-blocking**. There is no `sleep()` or `wait()` or anything like that. Functions like `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` can defer execution of a function to a later time, which is useful. However, the current script does **not** stop executing after those functions are called. It continues running until a separate built-in mechanism, whether it's a timer, a signal, or otherwise, executes the function that was specified in `setTimeout()`.

Answer (score 3):

Nope, and people's attempt with `Date` and a `while()` loop are such a bad idea I shouldn't have mentioned them. :P

You can, however, possibly achieve what you want with `setInterval()` or `setTimeout()` or a combination.

Answer (score 1):

A piece of code would look like:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            function executeAfter(caseVal) {
                switch(caseVal) {
                    case 0:                            // Code to execute before
                        alert("We are going for a sleep of 1 second");
                        setTimeout('executeAfter(1)', 1000);
                        break;
                    case 1:                            // Code to execute after sleep
                        alert("We are woke up");
                        break;
                }
            }
            executeAfter(0);
        </script>
    </head>
</html>
```